# UIViewController Not release when use closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I am use Alamofire to Get Data But ViewController Not Release when dismiss Viewcontroller if the process have not completed

```
func fetchingDataFromServer(url : String, completed:@escaping (Error?)->Void){

    Alamofire.request(url) .responseJSON {
        response in
        if let result = response.result.value as? [[String:String]]{
            if (response.error != nil){
                self.arrData = self.pasteData(result)
  //reload tableview data
                self.tbvData.reloadData()
                completed(response.error )
            }else{

            completed(nil)

            }


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `weak self` reference

```
func fetchingDataFromServer(url : String, completed:@escaping (Error?)->Void){

    Alamofire.request(url) .responseJSON { [weak self] (response) in
        if let result = response.result.value as? [[String:String]]{
            if (response.error != nil){
               self?.arrData = self.pasteData(result)
               self?.tbvData.reloadData()
               completed(response.error)
            }else{
              completed(nil)
            }
        }

    }
}
```